# Remover vinculação do Git no Projeto ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, github

Iniciei um projeto ASP.NET MVC e inicialmente utilizei o git para controle de código, mas agora quero transferir para o Team Foundation Services, como faço para desvincular meu projeto do git?

Comment: Deleta a pasta `.git` na raiz do projeto.

Comment: Obrigado @PedroCamaraJunior! isso mesmo!

Comment: Se você fez no Git e quer colocar no TFS... pode usar o Git no TFS! Ou lógicamente o TFVC... mas eu ficaria com o primeiro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como @pedro-camara-junior já comentou, basta excluir a pasta `.git` que está na raiz do seu repositório. A pasta é oculta, então não esqueça de habilitar a opção de visualizar Arquivos e Pastas Ocultos.

Todas as informações do `git` são salvas nesta pasta.
Obviamente, confirme que a sua cópia atual do projeto é a que você quer manter, porque todo o resto será perdido.